# how to create a project in turbo c++ 16 bit compiler

Tags: c++, c, ide, turbo-c++, turbo-c

I want to create a project file turbo c++ and link the files in this project. Although i have tried for it but i found only one option that to open a project no option to create a new project. So How to do that.

Comment: Are you really sure you want to be using a 16-bit compiler in 2010?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams:- In most of the universities and colleges this is the only compiler that you can use. Being a student you don't have much choice in this colleges.

Comment: @Manoj R:  _most_?  Really?  [Some, I could believe, but not most]

Comment: IS this collage also in a time machine.

Comment: Ok not the most in world. But the most in my city for sure. This can be easily found out at the time of campus interviews.

Comment: Have they never heard of DJGPP?

Comment: Yeah, why would you use TC when GCC is free (djgpp/code::blocks/etc)?

Comment: Unfortunately the Indian colleges all still seem to each with Turbo C/C++ and some really old and really bad text books (Let Us C, etc). This results in thousands of new graduates each year all writing `void main()`, assuming that ints are 16 bits, and relying on Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Which version of Turbo C is it?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, what you want to do, is to
"Open Project". There, you type in a projects name. It must end with `".PRJ"`. When you *open* it, it will be created. Then you can add files to the project by pressing "Insert". But have a look at the links below.

In case these links disappear from the Internet, I add some redundant links. The first is the best, also cool is the hundreds of pages long Turbo C manual.

[Graphical example with images!](http://www.horstmann.com/ccc/help/tc30dos.html)

[Turbo C manual on Scribd](http://www.scribd.com/doc/35398818/Turbo-C-Users-Guide-1987)

[In Turbo C 2.01](http://www.vintage-computer.com/vcforum/archive/index.php/t-4046.html)

[Using projects in Turbo/Borland C++](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/ap/workshop/material/turboproject.html)

[Also, information about porting MSDOS Turbo C programs to Linux](http://www.sandroid.org/TurboC/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use old Borland Turbo C++ (2.0 for DOS) project is text file with `.PRJ`extension.
You can open it like any text file (for example test.c) and write all your files into it.
Each row contains one .c or .cpp file without extension followed by its header in parentheses.
For example

```
mcalc (mcalc.h) 
mcparser (mcalc.h)
mcdisply (mcalc.h)
```

...
Here `mcalc.c` has `#include "mcalc.h"`  so that is why it is included in PRJ file.
Other headers for example `#include <stdio.h>` are not included in `.PRJ`.
Of course, if your .c has not any header written by you, `.PRJ` contains file name of your .c without additional parentheses.

After you create your `PRJ`, save it. In TC editor set project name (Project->Project name) using name of your `.PRJ`.
And that's it.