# How to build a DLL from C source code?

Tags: dll, compilation

I have 4 C-source files that I need to build into a DLL:

```
fl262x.c
fl262x.h
fl262x.fp
fl262x.prj
```

They're available for download here:

- http://sine.ni.com/apps/utf8/niid_web_display.download_page?p_id_guid=E2E2A3038D074997E04400144FB7D21C

I'm proficient in VB.NET, but I'm absolutely lost when it comes to C/C++. How would I go about doing this?

I found these two Q&As:

- [Converting c source code to a dll](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5779034/722393)
- [C source code to Dll](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5766757/722393)

...but unfortunately the discussions are so far above my head I'm getting dizzy just looking up.

What advice would someone have for a stone-cold C beginner?

Comment: I dont know if this is relevant - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974992/how-to-create-a-project-in-turbo-c-16-bit-compiler

Comment: "What advice would someone have for a stone-cold C beginner?" - get a good C textbook and learn the language. You can't learn C from trial&error. Plus DLLs are not defined in the standard, nor are they common to C implementations.

Comment: @a3f: I looked at the Q&A that you proposed as a duplicate. Since that discussion is about C++ and VBA, I'm not understanding why you consider it a possible duplicate of this C question.

Comment: @Olaf: I try to avoid shooting squirrels with shotguns wherever possible  ;-) This is a small, rare, one-off project; the odds of a similar need arising down the road are infinitestimally low. Deep study would be a waste of time/money at this point. I didn't write the code, I just need to build it. I'm hoping someone can assist with a relatively straightforward explanation of how to do so.

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez: Thank you, but I don't think C++ techniques will work for this C code. Please correct me.

Comment: @InteXX except for different file extension and symbol mangling, mmorris's answer seems like what you're after. You need to find out what the  .fp file is about though (.prj is probably just a project file you can ignore).

Comment: In that case, it is pointless to add the language tag. Better you add your toolchain. On a sidenote: Learning is **never** lost time/money. If nothing else, it will give you the greater picture. But as I know how much most people struggle not to learn, I fully understand your point.

Comment: @a3f: Would you enter your `gcc` suggestion as an answer...  I'd like to accept it.

Comment: @Olaf: "`Learning is never lost time/money.`" I hear you, and I agree. In this case, unfortunately, the requirement has been unexpectedly dropped in my lap and I'm facing an horrific deadline to get it built.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this source must be built with NI's LabWindows/CVI tool, the latest version of which is available for evaluation here:

http://www.ni.com/lwcvi/download/

In addition, the LWCVI runtime must also be installed on the machine where the .DLL will be used. The runtime is no-cost and is available here:

http://www.ni.com/download/labwindowscvi-run-time-engine-2017/6616/en/

The .DLL also depends on the NI-VISA runtime, which again is available at no cost:

http://www.ni.com/download/ni-visa-run-time-engine/7222/en/